# Counter-example or mistake code snippets

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I'd like to be able to have an option when writing code snippets to identify it graphically as a counter-example or a demonstration of a mistake, not the actual code solution to the question.

I'm not a graphic designer so I don't know how it could visually distinguish itself; maybe red text? Red background-color?

Either way, I'd like some visual indicator so that someone breezing over the question will get an immediate impression that the code snippet is deliberately wrong for the sake of explanation and example.

Answer (score 4):

I just use comments to draw attention to the [intentional mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12898932/7116):

```
// this is wrong and you are wrong for using it
****pointer = *(*(*(++x))).x;

// this is correct
pointer = magic;
```

Comment: I do too, but sometimes I'm using a code snippet to represent output or [expected output versus actual output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506082/static-variable-in-java/12506089#12506089) and it doesn't feel appropriate to add comments. Nonetheless, this is a valid solution - +1.

Comment: you can also add headers to the top of the code block to tell readers what it's supposed to be

Answer (score 3):

You can use strikeout — rather carefully:

```
// This is wrong!
****pointer = *(*(*(++x))).x;
```

```
// This is correct
pointer = magic;
```

The magic is:

```
<s>

    // This is wrong!
    ****pointer = *(*(*(++x))).x;

</s>

    // This is correct
    pointer = magic;
```

Comment: (ab)useful feature!